# How to disable adding of control to any container except its parent in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Good day. I one time add my control to ParentControl.Controls. How to disable adding of this control to any container except its parent?

UPDATE:

```
public class CompositeControl : Control
{
    public CompositeControl(EmbeddedControl[] embeddedControls)
    {
        this.Controls.AddRange(embeddedControls);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is EmbeddedControl) c.Locaion = new Point(someX, someY);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
}

public class EmbeddedControl : UserControl
{
}

EmbeddedControl uc1 = new EmbeddedControl(); //design by user
EmbeddedControl uc2 = new EmbeddedControl(); //design by user
EmbeddedControl[] coll = new EmbeddedControl[] {uc1, uc2};
CompositeControl compControl = new CompositeControl(coll);

Button b = new Button();
compControl.Controls.Add(b);
b.location = new Point(100, 100);
...
compControl.Controls.Remove(b); //ok
```

I want to make it impossible:

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.Controls.Add(uc1); //uc1 will removed from compControl.Controls
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far, and a code sample of how you wish to use this.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own panel class which inerhits from Panel. If someone add a control via the method you delete it internaly. I hope this is what you want to achieve.